# Google Maps API v2 grey screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to create and application that connects with Google maps. But when the screen loads where the map should be its just grey. How do I fix this?

The important message from my logcat.

```
06-11 03:32:55.196: E/Google Maps Android API(11671): 
Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: my pacakage,
 API Key: my key, 
Certificate Fingerprint: my fingerprint
```

The Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class mapPage extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_page);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
    android:name="my package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="my package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- External storage for caching. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- My Location -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
  <!-- End of copy. -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="my key"/>

        <activity
            android:name="my package.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name=".main">
               </activity>

         <activity android:name=".mapPage">
              </activity>

         <activity android:name=".ThirdPartyWeb"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">  

              </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkGrey"/>

        <Button 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/menuButton"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_menu"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"/>

         <Button 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_off"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"/>

       <EditText          
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/"
        android:id="@+id/seachBox"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

       <Button 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:background="@drawable/graphic_search"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_width="20dp"/>

       <ImageView 
        android:layout_above="@+id/newsFeed"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkGrey"/>

       <TextView 
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_above="@+id/newsFeed"
           android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
           android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:text="@string/news_feed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <ListView 
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:id="@+id/newsFeed"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">"

       </ListView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok problem solved. On the google api console, there is two google map api v2's. I had the one just for google maps api v2 if you look just above it, it says google maps v2 android. I turned on that one as well and the map is running.

Comment: You don't need the Google Map API V2 on as this is the javascript API for web based applications / websites.

Answer (score 4):

As it looks from the error, it seems that your configurations in the Google's API Console is wrong. Take a look at this blog post I wrote and make sure you are doing all the steps correctly:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Comment: the thumbprint api key and package name all match in my api console

Answer (score 1):

@rajwant rai: maybe your code is for API v1, because I use API v2 and such code is not necessary.

@author: Do you test it on the phone or emulator. Phone must have some google services installed for the map to work.
How to prepare working project is more described here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Answer (score 1):

There are two mode. release mode and debug mode, if you want to use in release mode, then u want to custom create fingure print. debug mode is usual mode.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key

See Displaying the release certificate fingerprint and debug certification fingure print in doucmentation

Comment: I'm signing an application every time and moving the apk to my device to debug and my key and everthing match my api console

Answer (score 0):

try to add following to manifest file (after meta-data tag)

```
 <uses-library
    android:name="com.google.android.maps"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: this is a google api v1 permission and is not needed in google api v2

Comment: @techroid  Your suggestion is only valid for Maps V1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but for me the app stopped working. I found out that it was problem with debug.keystore that Eclipse generate. It may happens when:

- source code is updated from repo but `debug.keystore` is get from local directory `USER_DIR.android\debug.keystore`
- you have disc failure and you did not restored old `debug.keystore`
- you deleted `USER_DIR.android\debug.keystore` somehow

To confirm this problem get SHA1 from your `USER_DIR.android\debug.keystore` and compare with the one from [Android Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect). They must be the same. If not try to generate new *Key for Android apps* by following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#create_an_api_project_in_the_google_apis_console).

Once you get it then update your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="NEW_API_KEY"/>
```

and clean whole `./bin` directory. Make it manually, don't trust *Project -> Clean...* option in Eclipse. Uninstall app from device before installing new one.

To avoid this problem in the future add your debug keystore to repo. Keep release in secret.