# Monodroid Google Maps API v2 - Error contacting Google servers

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, xamarin.android

I am developing a MonoDroid project and can't seem to get past this issue. I am trying to use the [MapsAndLocationDemo_v2](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2) project and can't even get the maps to load on the SimpleMapDemo project. I have gone through many SO posts concerning this issue.

The map loads but is white and Application Output states:

```
[Google Maps Android API] Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
[Google Maps Android API] Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I built the Google Play Client Services Library by following the instructions in the project [README.md](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2/README.md).

I generated a new Android Google Maps v2 API Key using the debug.keystore located at:

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore
```

and replaced the one in the project manifest.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="4.0" package="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsandlocationdemo2">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
<uses-permission ndroid:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Notice here that we have the package name of our application as a prefix on the permissions. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsandlocationdemo2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsandlocationdemo2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. This key will not work for you.-->
    <!-- See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxMY_KEY_HERExxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

[image]

My Android device is running 4.0.3. Google Play Services is installed and up to date on my device.

Any suggestions would be welcome...

Comment: Usually this means that you have the wrong API key. Which keystore did you use? The debug one or one you made yourself. If the latter, remember to specify it in your csproj file.

Comment: Thanks, I am using the debug keystore created by the IDE during a build. I have also tried deleting this keystore and regenerating it (via building project) and recreated my api key using this keystore. No dice...

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have really signed your application with the same key which you had used to get the API key.

And that the application package is the same as was in API key request.

I've lost a few hours with the problem to find out that there was something wrong with application signature.

I've signed it manually and map appears.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [how to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21207946/2974624) if your app is signed with valid key - otherwise Google Map will not work correctly, auth will be rejected or other such problems.

Check also logcat which probably prints out the reason of this problem.